# $T^2$, the two dimensional torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

How is the two dimensional torus $T^2$, different than a torus?  I'm supposed to construct a universal cover of $T^2$ as part of an assignment but I just want to make sure I'm working on the right problem.  My guess is that there is no difference and $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ which is just the normal torus we're used to.

Comment: What are your definitions of "two dimensional torus $T^2$" and "a torus"?

Comment: I guess that you are seeing mathematical descriptions of these objects, it would help to know what they are.

Comment: The problem just asks, "Find the universal cover of $T^2$, the two dimensional torus."  That task isn't two hard at all now that I know that it's just the normal torus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ is what is often just called a "torus".  More generally, an "$n$-dimensional torus" is a product $T^n=(S^1)^n$ of $n$ copies of $S^1$.